# XLSX returns strange characters from Buffer Object/Base 64

Tags: javascript, node.js, xlsx

I'm trying to read an Excel file which has been converted into a base-64 string. The File was originally a `react-dropzone` file before conversion. Unfortunately, when parsing the data with `XLSX` the file is returning unusual characters. Below is my code:

```
const XLSX = require("xlsx")

const file = "base64String"

const buffer = Buffer.from(file, 'base64')
const workbook = XLSX.read(buffer, { type: 'buffer' })

const sheetNamesList = workbook.SheetNames
// parse excel data to json
const excelData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetNamesList[0]])
```

When logging the excelData, the output returns something like:

```
'u«ZjeÆ­ÿ¾wh¥éñWè®f­³ê\u001f~\'\u001ev.éí²ÞiÛ!yëfÈ^zÖÚ±î¸PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\u0006\u0000\b\u0000
\u0000\u0000!\u0000bîËNÃ0\u0010E÷HüCä-JÜ²@\b5íÇ\u0012*Q>ÀÄÆªc[û\u0010B¡\u0015j7±\u0012ÏÜ{2ñÍh²nm¶Æ»R\fÈÀU^\
u001b7/ÅÇì%¿\u0017\u0019rZYï
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `file` isn't just a base64 string. In your repl.it, you have additional pieces of data prior to the base64 content, so that is being interpreted as junk base64 content.

If you strip away the `data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,` part, then the buffer should be able to properly parse your content.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if directly related, but by removing the string that you mentioned it returns an error: `Corrupted zip : can't find end of central directory`

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the entire file, then. Also I've noticed on your repl.it, you still have an extraneous `base64:` prefix

Comment: That was actually very insightful. The problem was with the base64 string not including the full document, basically because the library I was using `react-dropzone` library seems to only be capable of encoding the full-file during the initial event.